# Remove images only from DIV not whole site

Tags: javascript, image, hide

I only want to remove images from a content div, not the whole site. I have tried the following:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
```

That removes every image.

```
var elements = document.getElementsById('content').document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
```

That did nothing.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var elements = document.getElementsById('content').document.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

should be

```
var elements = document.getElementsById('content').getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = document.getElementsById('content').getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

if using jQuery

```
$('#content img').hide();
```